# I want to be able to "turn on" a video game console but only if the TV channel is set to 3. How do I do this?

Tags: java, class

Don't mind the other parts of my horrible code, still learning. I'm just trying to, through my "Console" class, create a method to "playGame" but only if my "TV" class's "channel" is set to 3.

My program says it doesn't have any errors but when I run my program and set the channel to 3, I still can't play the game. I keep getting the println "You need to change the channel to 3 before you can play."

Here are my classes:

**Console.java**

```
    public class Console {

        TV tv = new TV(5,25);

        private boolean isOn;
        private String reset;

        public Console(boolean isOn, String reset) {
            super();
            this.isOn = isOn;
            this.reset = reset;
        }

        public void powerButton() {
            if (isOn) {
                System.out.println("You turned off your video game console.");
                isOn = false;
            } else {
                System.out.println("You turned on your video game console.");
                isOn = true;
            }

        }

        public void reset () {
            System.out.println("You reset your game console.");
        }

        public void playGame() {
            if (tv.getChannel() == 3) {
                System.out.println("You play a game on your console.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("You need to change the channel to 3 before you can play.");
            }

        }

        public boolean isOn() {
            return isOn;
        }
        public String getReset() {
            return reset;
        }
    }
```

**TV.java**

```
    public class TV {
        private int channel = 10;
        private int volume = 25;
        public TV(int channel, int volume) {
            super();
            this.channel = channel;
            this.volume = volume;
        }

        public void channelUp () {
            channel++;
            System.out.println("The channel is now on channel " + channel);
        }

        public void channelDown () {
            channel--;
            if (channel < 0) {
                channel = 0;
            }
            System.out.println("The channel is now on channel " + channel);
        }

        public void volumeUp () {
            volume++;
            System.out.println("You changed the volume to " + volume);
        }

        public void volumeDown () {
            volume--;
            if (volume < 0) {
                volume = 0;
            }
            if (volume > 100) {
                volume = 100;
            }
            System.out.println("You changed the volume to " + volume);
        }

        public void currentChannel() {
            int currentChannel = channel;
            System.out.println("The current channel is " + channel);
        }

        public void changeChannel(int changeToChannel) {
            channel = changeToChannel;
            System.out.println("You changed the channel to " + channel);
        }

        public int getChannel() {
            return channel;
        }
        public int getVolume() {
            return volume;
        }
    }
```

EDIT(adding Main class and output)

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
//GameRoom
        Light light = new Light ("Modern");
        Macbook macbook = new Macbook ("2013", "Aluminum");
        TV tv = new TV (25,50);
        Bed bed = new Bed ("Double",3,2);
        Console console = new Console (false, "reset");

        light.turnOn();
        light.getStyle();
        light.turnOff();

        macbook.macbookDetails();

        tv.channelDown();
        tv.channelDown();
        tv.channelDown();
        tv.volumeUp();
        tv.volumeUp();

        bed.make();
        bed.messUp();
        macbook.playGame();
        macbook.turnOn();
        macbook.playGame();
        macbook.turnOff();

        console.powerButton();
        tv.currentChannel();
        tv.changeChannel(5);
        console.playGame();
        tv.changeChannel(3);
        console.playGame();
    }
}
```

***Output***

```
You turned on the light in the GameRoom
Modern style lamp.
You turned off the light in the GameRoom
--Macbook details--
Year: 2013
Color: Aluminum
The channel is now on channel 24
The channel is now on channel 23
The channel is now on channel 22
You changed the volume to 51
You changed the volume to 52
You made your bed.
You messed up your bed.
You need to turn on your Macbook first.
Macbook turned on.
You played Celeste on your Macbook.
Macbook turned off.
You turned on your video game console.
The current channel is 22
You changed the channel to 5
You need to change the channel to 3 before you can play.
You changed the channel to 3
You need to change the channel to 3 before you can play.
```

Comment: 1) You don't need to call super() if the class doesn't extend anything. 2) What is the code you are using to set the channel to 3?

Comment: 1) Thanks for letting me know!
2) In my Main class, I either use "tv.changeChannel(3)" to get to channel 3 or I repeatedly use "tv.channelDown(or tv.channelUp)" to get to channel 3.

Comment: which `TV` instance are you using? Please post your main class, don't describe it.

Comment: @jayweezy The `TV` that you're changing channels on is not the `TV` that your console is using.  The console has its own, internal `TV` instance that you have no way of changing the channel on.  I recommend you add `TV` as a parameter in the `Console` constructor so you can pass in an existing `TV` that you have access to.

Comment: @f1sh Sorry about that. I edited and added the Main class and output.

Comment: @Jordan That makes sense. Thank you. But how would I go about "adding TV as a parameter in the Console constructor?"

Comment: Console has it's own `TV` instance that it checks the channel for. You create a different TV and change the channel there...

Comment: @f1sh Thank you. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: @jayweezy You see how you're passing in `isOn` and `reset` as parameters into your `Console` constructor?  Add a third `tv` parameter, and set `this.tv = tv;` in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because there is two different instances of the TV class.

One in console

```
public class Console {

    TV tv = new TV(5,25);
```

and one in the entry point

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    //GameRoom
    Light light = new Light ("Modern");
    Macbook macbook = new Macbook ("2013", "Aluminum");
    TV tv = new TV (25,50);
```

So when you refer to tv.changeChannel(3) in the entry point, this is different instance of TV from when you refer to tv.getChannel() in console.

To fix this you need to pass in a reference of the TV instance created in the entry point, to console.

I would create a setter method that gives the TV object to console, and then call the method from the entry point.

```
//Console
public void setTV(TV tv) {
    this.tv = tv;
}

//Main
console.setTV(tv);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Works perfectly now. @Jordan's answer in the comments above worked as well. Not sure which one is better to use though. Anyone know which one is better?

Comment: @jayweezy It's just personal preference really. If TV is an essential parameter when creating a Console, then you should probably put it in the constructor. But if its less essential then you can just make a setter method. However if you add too many parameters too the constructor it can look a bit messy, so I generally prefer using setter methods unless its essential.